# String cannot be converted to JSONObject, im trying to connect android to phpmyadmin

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-asynctask

I'm trying to do a log in app that connects with phpmyadmin(musql) using php adn android. When I start the app I get an exception. its not a problem with the localhost ore the connection.

This is the PHP code----

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new user row
 * All user details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['lname']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['location']) && isset($_POST['contact'])) {

    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users( username, password,first_name, last_name, location, contact) VALUES( '$username','$password','$fname', '$lname','$location','$contact')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "User successfully Registered.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

This is the Java code------

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText fname;
    EditText lname;
    EditText username;
    EditText password;
    EditText location;
    EditText contact;

    Button btnreg;
    Button btncancel;

    // url to create new product
    private static String url_new_user = "http://192.168.0.xxx/android_test/newUser.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Edit Text
        fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);
        lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
        location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addr);
        contact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact);


        // Create button
        btnreg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnreg);
        btncancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncancel);

        // button click event
        btnreg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });

        btncancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Registering New User..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String Firstname = fname.getText().toString();
            String Lastname = lname.getText().toString();
            String Username = username.getText().toString();
            String Password = password.getText().toString();
            String Address = location.getText().toString();
            String Contact = contact.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", Firstname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", Lastname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", Username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", Password));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location", Address));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contact", Contact));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_new_user,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat from response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {

                    return "hooray";

                } else {
                    // failed to create user
                    Log.d("failed to create user", json.toString());

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null) {
                // successfully created a user
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                // closing this screen
                finish();
        }

    }
    }
}
```

This is the class in Java----

```
public class RegActivity extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText fname;
    EditText lname;
    EditText username;
    EditText password;
    EditText location;
    EditText contact;

    Button btnreg;
    Button btncancel;

    // url to create new product
    private static String url_new_user = "http://192.168.0.1XX/android_test/newUser.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Edit Text
        fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);
        lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
        location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addr);
        contact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact);


        // Create button
        btnreg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnreg);
        btncancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncancel);

        // button click event
        btnreg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });

        btncancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Registering New User..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String Firstname = fname.getText().toString();
            String Lastname = lname.getText().toString();
            String Username = username.getText().toString();
            String Password = password.getText().toString();
            String Address = location.getText().toString();
            String Contact = contact.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", Firstname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", Lastname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", Username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", Password));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location", Address));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contact", Contact));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_new_user,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat from response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created a user
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create user
                    Log.d("failed to create user", json.toString());

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

this is the logcat-----------

```
08-25 16:48:30.499: E/JSON Parser(1410): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException:  
     Value <br of  type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-25 16:48:30.509: W/dalvikvm(1410): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught
    exception(group=0x409961f8)
08-25 16:48:30.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1410): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-25 16:48:30.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1410): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while   
    executing doInBackground()
08-25 16:48:30.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1410):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
08-25 16:48:30.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1410):     at 
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
08-25 16:48:30.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1410):     at  
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
08-25 16:48:30.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1410):     at 
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
```

Comment: phpmyadmin is not a data base

Comment: phmyadmin is a DB administration website. it's NOT a database. unless you're trying to create a front-end for the phpmyadmin front-end, there's no reason you should be trying to connect to phpmyadmin itself. Oh, and you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server and your app pwn3d.